# Бот не регистрирует на команды

Tags: python, discord, disnake

У меня есть бот для Discord (python, Disnake), всё работало хорошо, но после перезапуска файла бота он перестал регистрировать команды. Все права у бота есть (всё работало).Ещё у него пропал значок
*поддерживает команды* и ещё срабатывает ивент bot_ready, но команд не регистрирует. Все файлы в папке `cogs` есть и работают (работали).

код:

```
from disnake.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=None,reload=False)
bot.remove_command("help")
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Бот готов!")
    bot.load_extensions("./cogs")

bot.run(<token>)
```